# Display Realm List data in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, realm

These are my three objects:

Workout.swift:

```
@objc dynamic var id = 0
@objc dynamic var date: Date?
// List of exercises (to-many relationship)
var exercises = List<Exercise>()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
```

Exercise.swift

```
class Exercise: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    // List of sets (to-many relationship)
    var sets = List<Set>()
    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workout.self, property: "exercises")
}
```

Set.swift

```
class Set: Object {

    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?
    // Define an inverse relationship to be able to access your parent workout for a particular set (if needed)
    var parentExercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: Exercise.self, property: "sets")

    convenience init(numReps: Int, weight: Double, aNote: String) {
       self.init()
       self.reps = numReps
       self.kg = weight
       self.notes = aNote
    }
}
```

This is how I get the value from Realm:

```
var data:Results<Workout>!
var result:[Workout] = []
func retreiveData() { // Retreive data from Realm

    let realm = try! Realm()

    self.data = realm.objects(Workout.self)
    self.result = Array(self.data)
}
```

I am using `CVCalendar`, and this is how I get the workout from each day:

```swift
func didSelectDayView(_ dayView: DayView, animationDidFinish: Bool) { // When select date in dayView

    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.locale = Locale.current
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier:"GMT")!
    let date = dayView.date.convertedDate(calendar: calendar)!

    let res = result.filter { compareDate(date1:$0.date!, date2:date) }

    self.resultFromDayViewDate = res
    print("resultFromDayViewDate: \(resultFromDayViewDate)")

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Since there are three exercises registered today, the output gives me:

```
[Workout {
    id = 0;
    date = 2019-12-08 17:39:32 +0000;
    exercises = List<Exercise> <0x6000006ad320> (
        [0] Exercise {
            name = Barbell Biceps Curl;
            sets = List<Set> <0x6000006b50e0> (
                [0] Set {
                    reps = 1;
                    kg = 4;
                    notes = D;
                }
            );
        },
        [1] Exercise {
            name = Barbell Squat;
            sets = List<Set> <0x6000006b5200> (
                [0] Set {
                    reps = 1;
                    kg = 66;
                    notes = Fffd;
                }
            );
        },
        [2] Exercise {
            name = Cable Fly;
            sets = List<Set> <0x6000006b5290> (
                [0] Set {
                    reps = 1;
                    kg = 4;
                    notes = Df;
                },
                [1] Set {
                    reps = 1;
                    kg = 44;
                    notes = Gege;
                }
            );
        }
    );
}]
```

Now, I am trying to display these exercises in a `UITableView`. And since there are three exercises, there should be three cells. I am only trying to display the exercise names. This is what I've got so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    //return myWorkout.exercises.count
    return resultFromDayViewDate[section].exercises.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle,
                           reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    let workouts = resultFromDayViewDate[0].exercises

    for exe in workouts {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Exercise: \(exe.name)"
    }

    return cell
}
```

But this only display the last exercise, not all three of them? How can I do this?

Comment: hey bud, please do not include "Xcode" with your code problems. only include "Xcode" with Xcode related issues :)

Comment: You've asked 8 questions that are similar to each other. While we don't mind helping, you may benefit from any one of the online tutorials available. Ray Wenderlich has some awesome tutorials that cover your questions [Navigation](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5824937-swiftui-tutorial-navigation) and [Infinite Scrolling](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial) are excellent. This one from Apple covers edit and delete behavior [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
let workouts = resultFromDayViewDate[0].exercises

for exe in workouts {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Exercise: \(exe.name)"
}
```

With

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "Exercise: \(resultFromDayViewDate[indexPath.section].exercises[indexPath.row].name)"
```

Comment: Also, get rid of `cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")` since you've already dequeued the cell - no need to (and should not) create a new object also.

Comment: If there is no exercises added at all, it crashes at `return resultFromDayViewDate[section].exercises.count` with error message: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`. Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: @ChrisShaw ^ Do you know?

Comment: I think number of sections will default to 1 if you have no implementation of `func numberOfSections(in: UITableView) -> Int`, and then your code will deference `resultFromDayViewDate[0]`. Implement the `numberOfSections` function and make it `return resultFromDayViewDate.count`.

Comment: @ChrisShaw My `UITableView` only have one section, but multiple rows. I added return `resultFromDayViewDate.count` as you stated in `numberOfRowsInSection`, but it looks like it returns number of workouts, but I want it to return number of exercises

Comment: Show how `resultFromDayViewDate` is declared and populated. Explain its structure and how each part should relate to 'sections' and 'rows'. When is `didSelectDayView` called (as this repopulates the entire table), and is that really what you want? Is this in one table view controller, or transitioning between two? As @Jay said above, I'd step back and follow some tutorials at this point.